# Redirecting with query string

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use htaccess to redirect urls like

**/admin.php?/cp/myaccount&id=975**

to

**/admin.php?/cp/myaccount/edit_profile&id=975**

I've been searching around a lot but not found anything that will work yet. How can just get the id number part of the query string and pass it to the redirect?

Comment: So difference is `/cp/myaccount/edit_profile` from `/cp/myaccount` ?

Comment: yes. As above but with any id (always a number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)(?<!/edit_profile)&(id=\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/edit_profile&%2 [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: it did. Thanks for the help!